# Spring Secutiry retrieve Principal Object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need to retrieve exactly Principal Object in non default Spring chain (not in controller with Principle injection). I'm implementing some interceptor with my spring-websocket and client to set user Principal from oauth header token value.

Main problem now is that I can't just directrly fetch Principal object instead I'm getting username String.

I've created this method but it returns String (getting ClassCastException):

```
public Principal setApplicationAuthentication(String username) {
    UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
    Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails.getUsername(),
            userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
    return (Principal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out with invoking only this method:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

Authentication is already Principal (superclass) with class hierarchy

Comment: If you are inside a `@Controller` you can add `Authentication` as a method parameter and Spring will inject it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Principal setApplicationAuthentication(String username) {
    UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
    Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
            userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
    return (Principal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
}
```

And this will give you actual principal object that is currently logged in. 
Keep in mind that `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` contain `principal` object of type `Object`, so here you can set either `UserDetail` or `String`object depending on your requirements